# Crontab Enhancement

Tags: cron

I have 31 cronjobs in a crontab and I changed the dates every week after first 7 cronjobs is done. Is there an alternative to reduce this manual work?

I tried to set specific dates for each cronjob.
For example: **15 00 1,12,22 * * ....**

Is this a good alternative? I need some suggestions to improve my work.

Thanks.

Edit:
I want to run 31 test run every week on rotation, 3 test run each day.
The image below shows how the cronjob is set for first 21 test run.

```
00 00 * * 1 test run 1
00 09 * * 1 test run 2
00 17 * * 1 test run 3
00 00 * * 2 test run 4
00 09 * * 2 test run 5
00 17 * * 2 test run 6
00 00 * * 3 test run 7
00 09 * * 3 test run 8
00 17 * * 3 test run 9
00 00 * * 4 test run 10
00 09 * * 4 test run 11
00 17 * * 4 test run 12
00 00 * * 5 test run 13
00 09 * * 5 test run 14
00 17 * * 5 test run 15
00 00 * * 6 test run 16
00 09 * * 6 test run 17
00 17 * * 6 test run 18
00 00 * * 7 test run 19
00 09 * * 7 test run 20
00 17 * * 7 test run 21
```

On Sunday, I will set for the remaining test run and so on.

```
00 00 * * 1 test run 22
00 09 * * 1 test run 23
00 17 * * 1 test run 24
00 00 * * 2 test run 25
00 09 * * 2 test run 26
00 17 * * 2 test run 27
00 00 * * 3 test run 28
00 09 * * 3 test run 29
00 17 * * 3 test run 30
00 00 * * 4 test run 31
00 09 * * 4 test run 1
00 17 * * 4 test run 2
00 00 * * 5 test run 3
00 09 * * 5 test run 4
00 17 * * 5 test run 5

# (etc.)
```

Comment: Can you say something about how you want the job to run? If you want a job to run on several specific dates, then yes, specifying several specific dates of the month would be the way to do that.  But you don't say anything about the original jobs being all the same or different from each other, or whether there is one job for each day etc. Do "31 cronjobs" mean one per day, or is that the number of jobs you have, and you need to run them every day?

Comment: I have 31 different jobs, I trigger 3 jobs each day which means in a week there will be 21 jobs running. So every Sunday, I change the date for the upcoming week for the remaining jobs.

Comment: You keep saying you change the dates but not by _how_.  If it's because you want the jobs to run on a certain day of the week, there is a cron table field for that- typically the last before the command to execute - that specifies the weekday(s) on which to run a job.

Comment: Yes thats how I change, ex: 15 00 * * **1** Now to minimise the manual work, I am finding alternative for that. Maybe set one job to run two weeks once. But not sure on how to edit the cron table field.

Comment: Please provide the schedule table you want to run. Currently I can't get what and when you want to run

Comment: Consider using `systemd.timer` which is more suitable for managing multiple jobs and you can configure it like a calendar, currently, provided that `systemd` is used

Comment: @RomeoNinov I have added some info in the question

Comment: @山河以无恙 im not familiar with systemd.timer.. will read on it

Comment: "_I want to run 31 test run every week on rotation, 3 test run each day_" - that doesn't add up. Three jobs a day is 21 jobs a week. What's with the remaining 10?

Comment: @roaima as i mentioned i will be setting cronjob for the remaining 10 test runs on mon, tue, wed and for the remaining day in that week... will start back from test run 1 again.

Comment: It doesn't say that anywhere. Is that what's in the picture? Please don't post pictures of text

Answer (score 4):

If you merely want to cycle through 31 tests continuously at specific start times, just use a script to keep track of the next job to be run, using a sequence number in a file.

Use a single permanent crontab entry to specify all the hours, like:

```
0 0,9,17 * * * /home/paul/JobRotate >> /home/paul/JobRotate.log 2>&1
```

This is a sample script to keep the latest job number in a .seq file, which it creates if it does not exist.

```
#! /bin/bash --
#.. This is /home/paul/JobRotate.
fn="/home/paul/JobRotate.seq"
[[ -r "${fn}" ]] && read -r Seq < "${fn}"
(( ++Seq ))
printf '%d\n' $(( Seq % 31 )) > "${fn}"
/home/paul/kJob_${Seq}
```

This is a sample of a job test script.

```
#! /bin/bash --
printf '%s\n' "I am kJob_17" >> /home/paul/JobRotate.log
```

Note the use of full path names: cron does not log you in, so your profiles (including PATH) are not activated. The environment is hostile: this is **all** cron gives me -- not even my default login shell.

```
LANGUAGE=en_GB:en
HOME=/home/paul
LOGNAME=paul
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
SHELL=/bin/sh
PWD=/home/paul
```

If your "test run x" names are not as standard as shown, you could map them using an indexed array, or a shell case statement, or access then via soft links that *do* have regular names.

Comment: You do have `$HOME` available

Answer (score 1):

Getting as idea the comment of Paul you can create wrapper script which will cycle from 1 to 31. The `cron` will become:

```
0 0,9,17 * * * wrapper_script
```

and the script itself will be something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
a=$(cat /tmp/var_)||exit 1
b=$(( ($a)%31+1 ))
run_script $b
echo $b>/tmp/var_
```

Do not forget to initialize the variable in `/tmp/var_` before first usage of the script